# Set systemwide proxy in windows using cmd

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, proxy, netsh

Is there a command that can replace the manual way of setting the system proxy:

```
PC setting -> Network-> Proxy -> Manual Proxy Setup
```

I found other answers mention using `netsh winhttp set proxy myproxy` but I have found that does not always work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Similar: [Set proxy through windows command line including login parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26992886/set-proxy-through-windows-command-line-including-login-parameters)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends on the applications you are using.
For some it is enough to set the following environment variable :

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://proxy_userid:proxy_password@proxy_ip:proxy_port
```

And if necessary :

```
set FTP_PROXY=%HTTP_PROXY%
set HTTPS_PROXY=%HTTP_PROXY%
```

For others, especially browsers, the following may do the job :

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyServer /t REG_SZ /d name:port
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyUser /t REG_SZ /d username
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v ProxyPass /t REG_SZ /d password
netsh winhttp import proxy source=ie
```

You may add to the reg commands the parameter `/f` to overwrite existing
entries without asking.

To undo, disable the proxy by setting `ProxyEnable` to 0.

And for still others this is a setting to be set in the program itself.